# How to change color of the bold text in Google search results using a user style sheet?

Tags: script, google-chrome-extensions, css, stylish

I'm trying to create a simple user style sheet (for Stylish) that would automatically highlight the bold parts of Google search results by turning them cyan (or any other color).

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution! The correct code is as follows:

em {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    color: #04B4AE !important;
    font-style: normal;
}